# Is there a faster way?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, optimization, intellij-idea

I want to change the background of three of my layout files. The problem is, it will take forever, because I have 8 of each for different screen sizes:

[image]

So, I was wondering. Instead of spending 10 minutes going into each and every file to change the background, is there any easier or faster way to change the background of all the files at once?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: Probably not.  But how come you have labeled this a "performance" and "optimization" problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set the background to a color or drawable (whichever you need).  Then you just have to change that color/drawable in the future.  Probably doesn't help you right now if you haven't set it up that way, but if you set it up this way in the future it will save time.

An even better solution is to use Styles and Themes correctly in your app.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html